# Angular2 carry over value of variable when changing pages

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a multi-page website (using the router) and would like to carry a variable value over from one page to the other.

On my contact form page, I have the following code:

```
testName:string = "hello";

ngOnInit()
{       
    this.dataService.Stream
        .subscribe(
            (city:City) => this.processData(city),
            (err) => console.log('Error at processing data'),
            () => console.log('Complete...')
        )
}

processData(city:City)
{
    console.log('the city name is: ', this.testName);
    this.problematicCity = city;
    this.testName = city.name;
    console.log('received data for city: ', this.testName);
}
```

When I'm on the main page and send a city to the data service, I get the following output in the console:

```
the city name is: hello
received data for city: Luxemburg
```

I therefore know that information is passed on correctly.
However, when I then go to the contact page, `testName` is changed back to 'hello'.

How do I prevent this from happening?
I have tried not initiating testName, but then I get the error: `assignment to undeclared variable string`.

Moving `testName:string = "hello";` to `ngOnInit` also results in the same error.

**Addition:** This is my data service:

```
//data.service.ts
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {City} from '../model/city.model';

@Injectable()

export class DataService
{
    Stream:Subject<City>;

    constructor()
    {
        this.Stream = new Subject();
    }
}
```

Comment: The `multi-pages website` statement is ambiguous : do you have a SPA (Angular with its router), or do you have your application on two separate tabs in your browser ?

Comment: Also, please post the code of your data service, as it might help us to see if you're making HTTP calls or using RxjS proxies such as `Subject` or `BehaviorSubject`

Comment: Added the info. Thank you.

Comment: u can pass the data on the url while u navigate like queryParam

Comment: The information is passed on fine. The problem is that the contact page seems to reset when you navigate to it, and doesn't take the data from the data service. Ideally, the page doesn't reset, but otherwise it should get data from the data service, if that data is available when it loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a `Subject` : this is a proxy that serves as an observable and an observer.

When you create a `[Behavior|Replay]Subject`, you're creating a **hot stream** : any observer subscribing to it will receive the last value of it.

This is different from a **cold stream**, like HTTP calls, where the whole stream is transmitted : once you have subscribed to it and the observable is finalized, you're not subscribed to it anymore.

In code words, it means everytime you create an instance of your contact component, you create a new subscription, and the subscription code is ran everytime you call `next` on your subject **OR** when you create a new subscription (hot streams get the latest value of the stream at their first subscription).

To avoid that, you can either limit your subscription to a single call, or delete your subscrpition at component destruction. I recommend the latter :

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.streamSubscription = this.dataService.Stream.subscribe(...);
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.streamSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: When is `ngOnDestroy` performed? Internet tells me it is 'when a component is destroyed'. If I change from my contact page to my main page, is that the moment the contact page is 'destroyed'?

Also, adding the unsubscribe function doesn't seem to work. If I add it, the contact form is receiving no information from the service anymore.

Comment: [According to the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks), it's performed when a component is indeed destroyed. A component is destroyed when it's not displayed in the screen anymore : on deletion, Angular calls `OnDestroy`. What do you mean exactly by `receiving no information from the service anymore` ? Can you be more explicit, something like "when I change routes and come back, nothign is displayed in the console" ?

Comment: Initially, I could see in the console that the contact page was receiving the data I was giving it from the main page. With the addition of `unsubscribe`, it no longer does (which makes sense if the contact page is unsubscribed when not displayed). Now, I never see the console show anything coming from the contact page, which leads me to think that it is never receiving information from the data service.

Comment: Well yes, that's kind of the point ... What behavior are you expecting ? Do you really want your deleted component to perform actions when you change data in your service ? Be warned that it's dangerous ...

Comment: @KKiek If you want to see the data you have sent to your service, you will have to reload your contact component, or subscribe to your service in a non-destroyed feature (such as the service itself, or the app component)

Comment: Then probably, `ngOnInit` is not the best place to subscribe to the service. What would be a good place to do so? I've tried `ngOnChanges`, but then I also get no output from the contact page in the console.

Comment: Again, you need to tell me your desired behavior. If you simply want to log when the value changes, you can do it in the service. The issue you have isn't with `ngOnInit`, but with your desired behavior, which has to do with what you want to do, and where you want to do it !

Comment: Sorry if I'm not very clear. I'm quite new to this kind of programming. What I want is pass information from the main page to the service. The contact page should retrieve the information from the service every time the user navigates to the contact page.

Comment: Then it's done already ! everytime you will open the contact page, the last value you have emitted will be displayed in your console. Your service, if it is a singleton (= injected into the highest module you have), will only hold the last value of the stream. If not, simply change your `Subject` to a `BehaviorSubject` (same principle, except that the `BehaviorSubject` starts with a value). I made a stackblitz to show you the principle : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1udpfm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts. Simply emit a value, then show the component.

Comment: Using BehaviorSubject seems to have done the trick! Thanks so much for the help.