# Subscribing triggers multuple times - Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

I am trying to use communication service to pass the date from one component to another, but after that subscribe triggers multiple times and at the end, the value I am trying to pass is `null`.

This is where I pass the value:

```
//all good, works fine, value is being passed
this.commService.regToken.next(this.tokenModel.value);
```

And in the `constructor` of other component I do this:

```
this.commService.regToken.subscribe( (value) => {
        this.value = value;
    });
```

Here is the issue, this subscribe triggers multiple times, `this.value` gets the right string, but after multiple subscriptions it ends up being `null`. How can I avoid this?

Comment: mm can you post more code of you triggers? ..maybe there's something clearing the value

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi there is nothing else, I just have this and I submit a for after, really small component

Comment: I have just answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52965449/angular2-carry-over-value-of-variable-when-changing-pages/52966063), I'll let you have a look at it.

Comment: @trichetriche I already tried with ngOnDestroy, but then I do not even get the value inside my OnInit? It doesn't subscribe

Comment: `Subject` or `BehaviorSubject` ?

Comment: @trichetriche Subject

Comment: Try with a Behavior then

Answer (score 0):

Unsubscribe if already subscribed

```
regTokenSubscription = null;

if (this.regTokenSubscription) {
    this.regTokenSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
this.regTokenSubscription = this.commService.regToken.subscribe( (value) => { this.value = value; });
```

Comment: Where should I put all this, inside constructor (except the variable)?